# how to set different styles to sns distplot in different subplots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, subplot

```
fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

sns.distplot(d,bins=200,color='green',ax=ax1)
sns.set_style(style='ticks')

sns.distplot(d,bins=200,color='green',ax=ax2)
sns.set_style(style='whitegrid') #this style is applied to both plots!

plt.show()
```

The code above makes set_style same for both sns distplots. I want to see visually different styles - ticks, whitegrid, darkgrid etc.

I also tried this, adding subplots without specifying axes in the first line, not working:

```
fig = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(11)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(12)

sns.distplot(d,bins=200,color='green',ax=ax1)
sns.set_style(style='ticks')

sns.distplot(d,bins=100,color='red',ax=ax2)
sns.set_style(style='whitegrid')

plt.show()
```

How to select distinct styles for each distplot?